# clang-format: Break after return type with __attribute__

Tags: c, clang-format

I have the following option set in my `.clang-format`:

```
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: All
```

However, if I have a function of the form

```c
int __attribute__((deprecated))
someFunc(void);
```

it gets reformatted to

```c
int __attribute__((deprecated)) someFunc(void);
```

Is there a way to get clang-format to get `AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType` to work with `__attribute__`?

This is version 14.0.0.

Comment: Does it insert a line break if you remove the attribute?

Comment: Yeah, it does.  Right after the return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though

```c
int
someFunc(void) __attribute__((deprecated));
```

is equally valid and works just fine with clang-format.